# How can I press several keys at the same time?JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, keypress, keyevent

How can I press several keys at the same time?
and the action was performed for each key
that is, I want to hold down a few keys on the keyboard so that the keys on the piano fall simultaneously

I have a virtual keyboard
And I need to press 6 keys at the same time
these 6 keys simultaneously fell
But now if you press several keys at once, then only one of them or two or three can fall

I want to create a virtual piano keyboard with the ability to press keys using a laptop keyboard
I need 6 keys to be pressed simultaneously
Please help, maybe someone came across this?

```
mainScene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() 
{
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.Q){
                whiteGL4.getTransforms().clear();
            }
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.W){
                whiteT7.getTransforms().clear();
            }
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.E){
                whiteGR3.getTransforms().clear();

            }
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.R){
                whiteT6.getTransforms().clear();
            }
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.T){
                whiteT5.getTransforms().clear();
            }
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.Y){
                whiteGL3.getTransforms().clear();
            }
}
mainScene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            if(event!=null){
                switch (event.getCode()) {

                    case Q:
                        rotateKey(whiteT7);
                        break;
                    case W:
                        rotateKey(whiteGL4);
                        break;
                    case E:
                        rotateKey(whiteGR3);
                        break;
                    case R:
                        rotateKey(whiteT6);
                        break;
                    case T:
                        rotateKey(whiteT5);
                        break;
                    case Y:
                        rotateKey(whiteGL3);
                        break;
}
```

Comment: You're not experiencing a software issue, but rather, a hardware limitation. Computer keyboards are wired according to a matrix, so keyboard controllers can only register two (and sometimes three) keys at a time. You're going to have to figure out something else. Old fashioned synths (cheapie models intended for amateur use in the home) used to have dedicated keys above the main keyboard for specific, common, chords).

Comment: You can use the `game-loop` idea. https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835